# EF Core (3.1) tools: is there a way to downgrade a database to just the previous migration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

We are writing an EF Core 3.1 application in C#. Currently, the data model is in constant change so I wrote a couple of scripts to automatise the `downgrade DB`/`remove migration`/`add migration`/`update DB` cycle.

This serves me well for the first migration but I'm reaching the point where I'd like to keep the base data between cycles: add a new migration and only revert and re-create the last one.

for removing and addning migration as well ad upgrading the database, there is no problem. But I don't have any command to revert the database just to the previous migration: I can use `dotnet ef database update` to upgrade to the latest, `dotnet ef database update 0` to remove all migrations but that's it.

Any suggestion?

**Edit**: I might not have made my real issue clear: I don't know the name of the last migration in my script so I can't reference it in `dotnet ef database update <last migration name>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about getting your last migration name using the following command. As far as I remember there is a filter switch which I don't remember.

```
dotnet ef migrations list
```

Update:

```
dotnet ef migrations list | select -last 2 | foreach {*do something here*$_}
```

Now, you can put your update or migration command there.

Comment: Now that is a good idea. Thanks: I think I can work with that

Answer (score 4):

`dotnet ef database update <previous-migration-name>` and then `dotnet ef migrations remove` to remove last migration

e.g. If you have migration1 -> migration2 -> migration3 then in order to revert your database to previous migration you would run `dotnet ef database update migration2` and then `dotnet ef migrations remove`

Comment: Thanks but that isn't actually what my problem is: the script doesn't know the name of the previous migration and I would like to avoid having to hard-code the migration names in it.

Comment: Then you would have to somehow find its name on code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else with the same problem making use of visual studio. Navigate to the package manager console.
View > Other windows > Package manager console

`Update-Database MigrationName`
This reverts the database to the migration specified.

`Remove-Migration` 
Removes the last migration.

Comment: Thanks but that isn't actually what my problem is: the script doesn't know the name of the previous migration and I would like to avoid having to hard-code the migration names in it.